# Google Sheets Script to Duplicate & Rename Spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm creating a script in Google Sheets that will copy the active sheet and create 30 duplicate sheets within the same workbook. Each duplicated sheet will have a different name based on the value within a cell on the active sheet. The cell will contain a date; duplicated sheets will have names of dates after the date listed in the cell. Example, cell B3 is "7/5/2019". The duplicated sheets should be named, "July 6, 2019" (B3+1), "July 7, 2019" (B3+2), & "July 8, 2019" (B3+3), etc.

I'm using code that is already embedded within Google Sheets. Some of it was created by recording a macro and other parts were created through what little I know about coding and research online.

```
function duplicatesheet(){

//copy active sheet
var as = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().duplicateActiveSheet();

//rename sheet
var myValue = 
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange('B3').getValue();
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().renameActiveSheet(myValue);

}
```

The code works in duplicating the active sheet once, but it is not making 30 duplicates. It is also not renaming the sheets properly as described above based on the date listed in cell B3. I need help creating code that will accomplish both of those tasks.

Answer (score 4):

This is edited w.r.t. comments. You can also see the excellent answer by Tedinoz.

Try this code:

```
function duplicatesheet() {
  var as = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // active spreadsheet
  var s = as.getActiveSheet(); // first sheet object
  var dateCell = "B3"; // cell containing first date
  var N = 30; // number of copies to make

  var startDate = new Date(s.getRange(dateCell).getValue()); // get the date stored in dateCell
  var day = startDate.getDate(); // extract the day
  var month = startDate.getMonth(); // extract the month
  var year = startDate.getFullYear(); // extract the year

  // loop over N times
  for (var i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    var asn = s.copyTo(as); // make a duplicate of the first sheet
    var thisSheetDate = new Date(year, month, day+(i+1)); // store the new date as a variable temporarily

    asn.getRange(dateCell).setValue(thisSheetDate); // writes the date in cell "B3"
    asn.setName(Utilities.formatDate(thisSheetDate, undefined, "MMMMM d, yyyy")); // sets the name of the new sheet
  }
}
```

I suggest putting `N=30` there to something small, like `N=2` to see whether it works with your formatting first.

The formatting here used by the `Utilities.formatDate()` method, I have assumed it to be `MMMMM d, yyyy`, which will print tab names in this format:

> July 6, 2019

You may change it as you wish according to the reference [[3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)] below.

---

You can see the references for all the functions used here:

- [Sheet.copyTo() method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copyTo(Spreadsheet))
- [Sheet.getRange() method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column)
- [Java's SimpleDateFormat, used by Utilities.formatDate()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: Hey James. I'm going to try this tomorrow as I'm still traveling. I did want to call out that I only have (1) initial date listed in cell B3. There is not a list of dates in cells B4 thru B33. The duplicated sheets should increment the dates by 1 based on the date value in B3. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I've edited the answer now. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: James - this code worked. Thank you! Sorry, I left one thing out in my initial ask. Cell B3 needs to be updated with the new date on each duplicated sheet as well. Example - On the duplicated sheet named July 6 2019, cell B3 should read "7/6/2019". On the next duplicated sheet named July 7, 2019, cell B3 should read "7/7/2019". Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Please check the answer again.

Comment: This answer also works for me, however I encountered A problem that the timezone must be type:String. To solve this, I put "GMT" instead of undefined in `Utilities.formatDate(thisSheetDate, undefined, "MMMMM d, yyyy")` . Hope this helps to other people that encountered this problem

Answer (score 1):

This code takes the single date entered by the OP in Cell "B3" of sheet name, say, "Sheet1; it loops thirty times creating a duplicate of the initial spreadsheet, incrementing the data-based sheet name by 1 day each time.

To ensure accurate date math, it's suggested that the format of Cell "B3" should be in the same style ("MMMM dd, yyyy") as the proposed sheet names.

---

```
function so5691088602(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetname = "Sheet1";
  var basesheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);
  var newSheetName = new Date(basesheet.getRange("B3").getValue());
  var NumDups = 30;
  for (var i=0;i<NumDups;i++){
    basesheet.activate;
    var tempDate = new Date();
    var printdate01 = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(tempDate.setDate(newSheetName.getDate()+1+i)), "GMT+10", "MMMM dd, yyyy");
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: Sheet Date = "+printdate01);
    ss.insertSheet(printdate01, {template: basesheet});
  }
}
```

---

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Hey Ted. I tried this code, but I got "TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of null". I'm going to try running the code on my laptop at home to see what happens. Thanks.

Comment: That would indicate that “Sheet1” doesn’t exist.